# Two layouts, one in background

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create two layouts: the first lighted, the second, in background, less enlightened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both layouts in a `RelativeLayout`, and set the appropriate background color with desired transparency.

Answer (score 1):

you can use relative layout in which you can add another layout. Set the background of first to lighted and enlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout to contain them both.

About the "lighted" part - use the View.setAlpha for each Layout
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)